How extract langchain SQL Agent logs to variable or file?
When using langchain AgentExecutor with verbose=True it is displaying many logs on the console but I am not able to extract those logs to log file. I have tried callback handler from langchain docs but still it not catching all the logs.
FileCallbackHandler:
from langchain_core.callbacks import FileCallbackHandler
from loguru import logger

logfile = "sql_agent_output.log"

logger.add(logfile, colorize=True, enqueue=True, level="DEBUG")

handler_1 = FileCallbackHandler(logfile)

config = {
    'callbacks' : [handler_1]
}

Attaching console logs screenshot:

When I checked logs files there are partial logs:
[1m> Entering new ChatPromptTemplate chain...[0m

[1m> Finished chain.[0m


[1m> Entering new OpenAIFunctionsAgentOutputParser chain...[0m

[1m> Finished chain.[0m

[1m> Finished chain.[0m
[32;1m[1;3m
Invoking: `generate_sql` with `{'query': 'SELECT LocalityName, LivabilityScore FROM demo_user.Locality ORDER BY LivabilityScore DESC'}`


[0m[36;1m[1;3m[('Darwin City', 4.5), ('Larrakeyah', 4.3), ('Fannie Bay', 4.2), ('Nightcliff', 4.1), ('Parap', 4.0), ('The Gardens', 4.0), ('Leanyer', 3.9), ('Stuart Park', 3.8), ('Woolner', 3.7), ('Bayview', 3.5)][0m

[1m> Entering new RunnableSequence chain...[0m


[1m> Entering new RunnableAssign<agent_scratchpad> chain...[0m

Can some one help to hove to get all the verbose logs to file or variable?
